# If a css background image is overridden in later css, does it still get called?

Tags: css, image, background, overriding

If style1.css sets a background image and I override it in style2.css, does the background image still get called even though it's not being loaded?

I ask because I was running some diagnostics and I found some 403 (or maybe it was 404) errors pointing to that image, but I figured the image shouldn't be called anymore now that I'm overriding it.

Thanks!
Phil

Update:

When I inspect the element in Chrome, I can see that the css for the background image is being overridden, because it's crossed out.

And yet when I run the network image filter, I see the image is still being called, which gives a 404 error.

So that's why I wonder if overriding a css background image doesn't stop the original call to that image?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in chrome developer tool (network, filter Image) can browser call first image or not. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJcWf.png

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rnohnnte/1/  `In this downloaded only one image.`

Comment: Thanks for the clue Dima, yes, I can now confirm the image is still being called even though it has been overridden in other css.